# Install mrtg on boot

Tags: bash, unix, system-administration, boot, autorun

I am trying to install mrtg on boot.

```
apt-get install mrtg
```

is the required command.  But when installing it comes up with a GUI asking me to say "Yes/No".  This is good if I am running the script manually, but on boot it gets stuck.  Is there a work around?

The prompt I get is not the normal Y/N thingy.  ( This can be fixed using apt-get -y install ), but what I get is a kind of blue screen with a window popping up asking "Yes/No"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why** would you need to install it at boot? You should only need to install it *once*...

Consider using dpkg preconfiguration, to seed the answer to the Yes/No question. See http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/394 for more details on preseeding to automate installs.

Comment: I'm operating on Amazon.  I need to install when launching a new machine.  Also, I can create an image with this installed, but that is not an option for the current scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Well, creating an image is the more appropriate way to do it. Otherwise, use the suggested alternative for doing automatic installs.